# MS Access 2003 report concatenation

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2003

I am currently working on a report for MS Access 2003 with three fields consisting of a [Lease Start] Date, [Lease End] Date, and [Financial Notes] String.  The Management wants all three combined under Financial Notes on the Report.  I have set up the Concatenation as:

```
=CVar([Lease Start]) & " - " & CVar([Lease Ends]) & " " & [Financial Notes]
```

Yet I am getting a # Error when I run the report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See what that expression returns in a query of your report's record source.

```sql
SELECT
    CVar([Lease Start]) & " - "
        & CVar([Lease Ends])
        & " " & [Financial Notes]
        AS report_expression
FROM YourTableOrQuery;
```

I don't know whether this is significant, but I'm puzzled why you're using `CVar()` there.  When you give it a Date/Time value, it returns a Date/Time value.  Access *should* oblige by casting that to a string when you concatenate, but it would do the same for the original Date/Time value without `CVar`.  I don't understand why `CVar` is useful there.

Since you're building a string, my inclination would be to use `Format()`.

```sql
SELECT
    Format([Lease Start], "m/d/yyyy") & " - "
        & Format([Lease Ends], "m/d/yyyy")
        & " " & [Financial Notes]
        AS report_expression
FROM YourTableOrQuery;
```

However as I admitted, I have no clue whether this is a significant issue.

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to do the concatenation on the report itself instead of in the SQL query.  It worked perfectly.

Comment: OK.  I gotta confess I don't understand why the concatenation failed when you did it in the report instead of in its record source query.  But if you're happy, me too.  :-)